# independent, identically distributed (IID) random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I am having trouble understanding IID random variables. I've tried reading http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/iid.pdf, http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture32.pdf, and http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs70/sp13/notes/n17.sp13.pdf but I don't get it.

Would someone explain in simple terms what IID random variables are and give me an example?

Comment: say you are sampling from a known distribution with replacement.  Every time you, say, draw a sample, this is a random variable.  Drawn samples are independent of each other, and the distribution never changes.  Thus, IID random variables

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Im sure you know that iid means independent, identically distributed. I think the most prominent example is a coin toss repeated several times.

If $X_1, X_2, \dots$ designate the result of the 1st, 2nd, and so on toss (where $X_i = 1$ means that in the i-th toss you have got head and $X_i = 0$ tail), you have that $X_1,X_2,\dots $ are iid.

They are *independent* since every time you flip a coin, the previous result doesn't influence your current result. Edit: there is a mathematical definition of independence, but I don't think it is necessary at the moment.

They are *identically distributed*, since every time you flip a coin, the chances of getting head (or tail) are identical, no matter if its the 1st or the 100th toss (probability distribution is identical over time). If the coin is "fair" the chances are 0,5 for each event (getting head or tail).

Does that help?

Comment: An example of an identical dependent situation would help me :).

Comment: @jiggunjer How about this: Let $X_1$ be the result of flipping a coin, then let $X_{i+1}=X_i$ for all $i$. The $X_i$ are identically distributed - each variable has .5 chance of being 0 and .5 chance of being 1 - but they're as correlated as can possibly be.

Answer (score 5):

"**Independent**" means for any $x_i \in X$, $P(x_0, x_1,..., x_i) = \prod_0^i P(x_i)$

For example, toss 2 dice. Let $X_1$ be event of the first being {1, 2}, $X_2$ the first being {2, 3, 4} and $X_3$ the second being {6} and $X_4$ the second being {4, 6}. It's intuitive to conclude that $P(X_1 \cap X_2, X_3) = P(X_1 \cap X_2) P(X_3) = P(X_1=2) P(X_3)= P(X_2=2) P(X_3) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$, so are other combinations.

However, synonyms of "**identical**" include "alike" and "equal". That's, the probability of every variable should be equal, or identical. In the above example $P(X_1) \neq P(X_2)$ or $\frac{2}{6} \neq \frac{3}{6}$. To make $X_1$ and $X_2$ be indentical variables, we can let $X_2$ be event of the second die being {1, 6} or the first being {4, 2} or other similar posibilities you like. Then we get $P(X_1) = P(X_2)=\frac{1}{3}$.

"**Independent but not identical**" as shown in the above two instances, like any combinations of evens between two dice: $P(X_1)$ and $P(X_3)$ or $P(X_2)$ and $P(X_4)$ and etc.

"**Identical and independent**", any event combinations between the two dice that have the same probability. For example $P(X_1=1)$ and $P(X_3=6)$ and etc.

"**Identical but not independent**", any two events for one die. For instance, $P(X_1=1)$ and $P(X_2=3)$. **It is not independent since if the die shows you 1 you can not see a 3 at the same time, and hence the probability of seeing 1 and 3 at the same time while rolling one die is 0**.

"**Not identical and not independent**", any two events for one die with unequal probability, for instance $P(X_1)$ and $P(X_2)$ or $P(X_3)$ and $P(X_4)$, or $P(X_2=4)$ and $P(X_1)$ and etc.

Answer (score 0):

.So basically you will consider events where the outcome in one case will not depend on the outcome of the other cases .It is called identical because in every case u consider the possible outcomes will be same as the previous event .Some one has suggested yes tossing of coin is a good example .I will try to be a statistician here .You should go through few statistical distributions like normal ,gamma etc and then see additive property .There while proving the additive property u will consider independent events initially and then prove that the addition of all the independent variates also follows the respective distribution using the MGF of that particular distribution and then you will extend your property to see what if the variates are made similar .Hope you got your answer

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. This question has a well-accepted answer. You have provided nothing new. And what you have provided does not exactly answer the question. Please refrain from opening up old questions which have good answers unless you have something significant to contribute. THere are many new questions begging for answers.