# independent identical distribution?

Tags: statistics

I thought an identically distributed random variable meant sample/values are all drawn from the same distribution. But doesn't this depend on them also being independent? I.e. is identicality dependent on independence? I'm not talking about dependence between random variables, just the distribution of a single random variable like the result of a coin toss.

For example if I flip a coin that always returns the opposite of the previous toss--obviously a dependent distribution. On the first throw I throw heads (X=x1 is from the uniform distribution). On the second throw I'm sampling from a distribution where P(X=x1) is zero, right? So how can X, which is dependent, ever be identically distributed?

I've read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466927/independent-identically-distributed-iid-random-variables?rq=1) but that answer seems to imply I'm right: identicality is not possible without independence. I'd like either confirmation or a counter-example/proof.

Comment: The expression "an identically distributed random variable" (practicized in your question) does not make sense. The expression "identically distributed random variables" does make sense. In that case at least 2 (quite often more) random variables are involved that have the same distribution.

Comment: @drhab thank you. That part has been cleared up due to the answer by CM7F7Bb.

Answer (score 1):

We can have identical distributions without independence. As you described in your example, if $X$ has the Bernoulli distribution with $p=1/2$ then the random variable $Y$ given by
$$
Y=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if $X=1$},\\1,&\text{if $X=0$},\end{cases}
$$
has the same distribution (i.e. the Bernoulli distribution with $p=1/2$) despite the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are clearly not independent. In particular, $P(X=1)=P(X=0)=1/2$ and $P(Y=1)=P(Y=0)=1/2$. Hence, the distributions are the same.

Comment: So X and Y are different random variables. I guess by confusion came from thinking i.i.d. described a single random variable. Before I thought of multiple coin tosses as outcomes of the random variable X.

Comment: @jiggunjer We usually talk about iid random variables. I have never seen a definitiion of independent distributions and I do not think that such a definition would make sense. Yes, $X$ and $Y$ are two different random variables with their own distributions, which in this case are the same. If we toss a coin a number of times, we can model this experiment as a collection of random variables that each can take $0$ or $1$ as its value.